# Difference between SQL and LDAP

Tags: sql, ldap

I have used both SQL and LDAP, but in a recent conversation with one of my peers I came to realize that there may be more to it. And that it could be beneficial to consider LDAP over SQL at times.

So my challenge/request/question: Can you explain to me the advantages (and disadvantages) of LDAP over SQL "in the elevator". That is, a short 2-3 minutes presentation.

Comment: Comparing SQL and LDAP is like comparing bees to motorcycles IMO... unless I got the wrong idea of LDAP?

Comment: Then I think you got the wrong idea. Today most people put ALL types of data into SQL. I think in some cases LDAP is a better data store, but I'd like to hear some experiences/thoughts on it.

Comment: Agree with Tedd Hansen. They are both datastores, not that one is a datastore and the other is a network protocol for example, in that case BoltClock's assertion would be true.

Comment: Probably worth adding that a LDAP solution will not guarantee immediate synchronisation across servers (which is not considered a problem in non transactional systems) and also may involve redundancy of data in order to help users get useful answers to queries (which would be a Codd offence in the SQL world).

Comment: @TeddHansen None of them are actually datastores. LDAP is an application layer protocol for accessing directory services ( MS Active Directory, OpenLDAP ). SQL is a language used to access relational databases ( MySQL, MSSQL ... )

Answer (score 27, accepted):

LDAP is a protocol for accessing directories, SQL is a query language for databases.

Both systems store data, but the big difference is: **directories** (like Active Directory) are tuned towards a lot more reads than writes, e.g. reading information should be very easy, trivial indeed (and offer great performance), while updating can be a bit of a pain. Also: directories are often distributed, e.g. spread across multiple servers/locations, and offer mechanisms to easily replicate read-only data across locations.

SQL **databases** on the other hand are geared towards a more balanced load of read and write, and thus, writes must also be as easy as possible.

So this boils down to:

- if you have data (like user accounts, permissions) that are mostly read (but not very often updated), then a directory sounds like a great solution
- if you need to frequently insert new data and update existing data, then a database is much more suited to your needs. Don't try to create an order entry system inside a directory - it's a poor match.....

Those distinctions aren't "absolute" or clear - it's often a judgment call whether to put something into your database, or whether it belongs into a directory.

Comment: Thanks. Too bad I couldn't share the points as there were a more good answers here. From @Stegan Gehrigs link I also found that LDAP doesn't have relation, so that puts a serious constraint on the choice.

Answer (score 7):

The **Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP)**  is an application protocol for reading and editing directories over an IP network.  More [[**here**]](http://www.gracion.com/server/whatldap.html).

A good read on **LDAP** and its difference from Database is available [[**here**]](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch2/#database)

Also,check out the following links :

- [LDAP vs Relational Database (a)](http://blogs.oracle.com/treydrake/entry/ldap_vs_relational_database_part)
- [LDAP vs RDBMS](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books//network_administration_guides/ldap_administration/intro_LDAP_vs_RDBMS.html)

Answer (score 3):

There is a nice comparison available - but unfortunately its' in German only (and quite old, but that shouldn't matter as neither the basic notion behind SQL nor behind LDAP has changed since 2002): http://kris.koehntopp.de/artikel/dir-vs-rel/sld001.htm

Comment: Thanks. I found another page on the site that had English PDF: http://kris.koehntopp.de/artikel/sql-vs-ldap-kai-voigt/

Comment: The resource is no longer available at that address. Here is a link to the latest available cached version I could find. http://web.archive.org/web/20120814183608/http://kris.koehntopp.de/artikel/dir-vs-rel/sld001.htm